# Best/good way to remove linoleum squares on pine flooring

Tags: flooring, floor, linoleum

I have pine wood floors I want to refinish - but on top of the floor are square linoleum tiles.  The adhesive is really strong.  I tried pulling some up but it seems like a laborious task.  I am also wary of marring the soft wood underneath too much.  I am fine with some damage to the floor underneath, but not excessive wear.

anyone have suggestions on making this chore easier?

Comment: What is under the floor?  Is it a finished space?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MOtR69ylmQ

Comment: Step one - check the tile and adhesive for asbestos content.

Comment: There are long pole scrapers (in the flooring section of any big box) that might help. Generally, you don't want to get the adhesive hot (ie, oscillating tool scrapers), lest it turn into goo. That said, however, don't get your hopes up too much: the softwood floor might have been covered for a reason.

Comment: @dmoore, The floor is an upstairs bedroom.  So below it is living space